# Text field delegate in table view error: index is out of range swift

Tags: ios, arrays, swift, uitextfield, tableview

I am trying to get every input that typed in the text field. I used this in my other view it works, but here I have different case within 1 section (should be easier) but I don't why, the index is out of range. Here's the code:

```
import UIKit

struct SpecData {
var server: Int
var core: Int
var userCAL: Int
var deviceCAL: Int
}

var arraySpecDataInputed = [SpecData]()

extension SpecVC: UITableViewDelegate, UITableViewDataSource {
func numberOfSections(in tableView: UITableView) -> Int {
    return 4
}

func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
    switch section {
    case 1:
        return 4
    default:
        return 1
    }
}

func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
let inputCell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: LicenseInputTVCell.cellIdentifier, for: indexPath) as! LicenseInputTVCell

switch indexPath.section {
case 1:
        inputCell.labelSpec.text = specServer[indexPath.row].spec
        inputCell.textfieldInput.delegate = self
        inputCell.textfieldInput.addTarget(self, action: #selector(textFieldDidChange), for: .editingChanged)
        inputCell.textfieldInput.tag = indexPath.row
        
        return inputCell
default:
        return inputCell
     }
   }
}

extension SpecVC: UITextFieldDelegate {
     @objc func textFieldDidChange(_ sender: UITextField) {
         let rowIndex = sender.tag
         let indexPath = IndexPath(row: rowIndex, section: 1)
         let cell = tableView.cellForRow(at: indexPath) as! LicenseInputTVCell
         if rowIndex == 0 {
             arraySpecDataInputed[rowIndex].server = Int(cell.textfieldInput.text!) ?? 0 // Fatal Error: Index out of range
         }
     }
}
```

When I tried to start typing 1 digit of number in the textField, the app was error with index out of range. I tried to input some different numbers in the `[rowIndex]` but it doesn't work.
Can anyone tell me what did I do wrong here? What should be filled in the `[rowIndex]`?

Thank you in advance

Comment: where is the entry in arraySpecDataInputed allocated?

Comment: I don't quite understand, maybe I haven't created one? how can I create the entry?

Comment: something like arraySpecDataInputed.append(SpecData(server:-1,core: -1,userCAL: -1, deviceCAL: -1). then you can set the field values from input.

Comment: I don't think I need to do that, because using text field delegate it should be able to read every input you type. for example if I type 123, when I print it, it will print like: `1` , `12`, `123`

Comment: @AldoSugiarto - make your **cell** class conform to `UITextFieldDelegate` and handle `textFieldDidChange` inside that class... then pass the values back to your controller.

Comment: do you understand what your error means? It means there is no entry in your array to store the data into.

Comment: at least from what I see here (this piece of code) is that you didn't initialize your array anywhere. It is empty! It doesn't have any indexes, and that is why it just cant do anything. Use append() method for your array to be able to store the info.